# Matlab - insert/append rows into matrix iteratively

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, insert, rows

How in matlab I can interactively append matrix with rows?

For example lets say I have empty matrix:

```
m = [];
```

and when I run the for loop, I get rows that I need to insert into matrix.

For example:

```
for i=1:5
  row = v - x; % for example getting 1 2 3
  % m.append(row)?
end
```

so after inserting it should look something like:

```
m = [
     1 2 3
     3 2 1
     1 2 3
     4 3 2
     1 1 1
]
```

In most programming languages you can simply append rows into array/matrix. But I find it hard to do it in matlab.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`m = [m ; new_row];` in your loop. If you know the total row number already, define `m=zeros(row_num,column_num);`, then in your loop `m(i,:) = new_row;`

Comment: There is a big difference between `m=[m,x]` and `m(end+1,:)=x` when appending s column. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990695/7328782). For rows, the difference maybe not as large, I haven’t compared, but it is certainly recommendable to append columns rather than rows, if preallocating a matrix of the right size is not possible. Appending columns can be done without copying data in many cases.

Answer (score 3):

Just use

```
m = [m; row];
```

Take into account that extending a matrix is slow, as it involves memory reallocation. It's better to preallocate the matrix to its full size,

```
m = NaN(numRows,numCols);
```

and then fill the row values at each iteration:

```
m(ii,:) = row;
```

Also, it's better [not to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab) `i` as a variable name, because by default it represents the imaginary unit (that's why I'm using `ii` here as iteration index).

Comment: I just used m = NaN(numRows,numCols); as definition outside prior to the loop and then m(row,:) = row; inside the loop. That was it. tks!

Answer (score 1):

To create and add a value into the matrix you can do this and can make a complete matrix like yours. 
Here **row = 5** and then **column = 3** and for hence two for loop.

Put the value in `M(i, j)` location and it will insert the value in the matrix

```
for i=1:5
    for j=1:3
        M(i, j) = input('Enter a value = ')
    end
    fprintf('Row %d inserted successfully\n', i)
end

disp('Full Matrix is = ')
disp(M)
```

Provably if you enter the same values given, the output will be like yours,

```
Full Matrix is = 
1 2 3
3 2 1
1 2 3
4 3 2
1 1 1
```