# How does matrix assignment work in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix

Could someone explain to me this matrix assignment in MATLAB? I mean `D` matrix of course, the `D` matrix is empty at first and then I'm assigning to it `D` and `A1` but hows that possible if `D` is empty?

```
x = [1, 2, 4, 8];
D = [];
for k=x;
    A1 = 1./x;
    D = [D A1];
end
```

Comment: Look at this (duplicate?) question, which is about appending to a matrix in a loop. Appending to the matrix is exactly what you're doing, so see the answers for details about how to do it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20599260/matlab-insert-append-rows-into-matrix-iteratively

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matlab - insert/append rows into matrix iteratively](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20599260/matlab-insert-append-rows-into-matrix-iteratively)

Answer (score 0):

You are just overwriting your old `D` matrix with a new value, i.e. `[D A1]`.

`[D A1]` concatenates the `D` matrix (which is empty in the beginning) horizontally with `A1` (which is a row matrix).