# Difference between append and x = [x, element]

Tags: matlab

I've create an array `X` as `X = [1 2 3 4 5]` and I want to insert `0` at the end of it.

Is there any difference in using `X = [X, 0]` and `X = append(X, 0)`?

I didn't find anything about and I'm not sure if I can notice the difference.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As explained in the other answer, `append` is part of a toolbox, and not available to everyone.

The correct way to append to a matrix, however, is

```
X(end+1) = 0;
```

This is a whole lot more efficient than `X=[X,0]`. The difference is that this latter form creates a new array, and copies the original one into it. The other form simply appends to the matrix, which usually doesn't require reallocation. [See here for an experiment that shows the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48351041/7328782) (read the question and my answer for both parts of the experiment).

Answer (score 1):

`append` function is a part of Symbolic Math Toolbox. It's preferred to use `[X, 0]` as it is part of a core language and more likely to be understood.