# Can matlab colon operator be used with arithmetic operators?

Tags: matlab, operators

Let's say I want to make a `vector`:

```
A = [4 8 16 32]
```

Is there any way to do this using the `colon` operator ?
For example something like:

```
A = 4:(*2):32;
```

Comment: No, it cannot. The colon operator can only _add_ a fixed step to each value. But in this case you can transform your operation (multiplication) into a addition, and then convert back: `A = 2.^(2:5);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible in Matlab. You can use it like @Luis showed:

```matlab
A = 2.^(2:5);
```

Or if you want to do this with a different function in the future:

```matlab
A = [];
for n = 2:5
    A = [A n^2];
end
```

By changing the limits of the for loop and the n^2 part to your desired values, you can do it however you like.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Extending an array with `A=[A,n]` is highly inefficient. It is [much, much faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990695/7328782) to do `A(end+1)=n`. However, if possible, one should always [preallocate](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html) instead of repeatedly extending the array.