# Duplicate every odd row in an array with Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

Within Matlab I need to duplicate every odd row in an array excluding the first and last, for example:

```
g =  [5;    6;     11;     12;     17;   23;    24;     29;   30];
```

the code will manipulate it in to:

```
g =  [5;     6;     11;    11;    12;    17;    17;   23;    24;   24;     29;   30]
```

How can I generate this new sequence?

Comment: You text and example do not mach. You havent duplicated neither the first nor last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a nasty way of making this array. I'm saying it's nasty because it's hard to read what is going on, please put a lot of comments around this bit of code if you use it!

You want to create the set of indices `1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, ...`, repeating the odd ones (except 1, and also make sure the last one is not repeated). The sequence of repeated odd values is really the floor or the sequence `1, 2/3, 4/3, 6/3, 8/3, ...`, which is easy to generate: `1:2/3:N`. This creates the sequence `1, 1, 2, 3, 3, ...`, we need to remove the first element.

It turns out (by experimenting) that the index `N` doesn't get repeated if `N` is odd (as desired) but gets skipped if `N` is even. So we generate the index sequence up to `N+1`, and remove the last element. This way, `N` is not repeated if odd, but is always there.

So we have:

```
g =  [5; 6; 11; 12; 17; 23; 24; 29; 30]; % input data
indx = floor(1:2/3:numel(g)+1);          % indices with odd elements repeated
indx = indx(2:end-1);                    % remove first and last element
result = g(indx);                        % index
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
g =  [5; 6; 11; 12; 17; 23; 24; 29; 30];
n = size(g, 1);

f(1,:) = g(1,:);
for i = 2:(n-1)
   if mod(i,2) == 1
       f = [f; g(i,:)];
       f = [f; g(i,:)];
   else
       f = [f; g(i,:)];
   end
end
f = [f; g(n,:)];
```

where f is your new matrix.

Comment: It is always better to extend an array with `f(end+1) = g(i)`, because `f = [f;g(i)]` is very inefficient. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990695/7328782.

Comment: Renato, your a wizard.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this as well.

```
%Creating a vector f with double the number of elements
f = zeros(2*size(g,1),1)

%Insering an element of g into the even indices of f - odd indices are still zero
f(2:2:end+1) = g;

%Inserting an element of g into the odd indices of f - even indices already have the g values
f(1:2:end) = g;

%Remove every element from the second odd index
f(3:4:end) = [];

Edit 2:
There is also another way to use this.
n = 2; %number of times an odd element has to be repeated.
f = kron(g, ones(n*1,1)); % This is the Kronecker tensor product

f(3:4:end) = [];

This will also work.
```

Comment: Sorry! I have edited my answer to suit the question. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, I posted two solutions, yet you downvoted my answer.

Comment: No, I changed my downvote to an upvote after you edited your answer. There are currently no downvotes on your answer. And you can see on [your reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8028344/vijay-karthik?tab=reputation) that you don't have any downvotes at all.

Comment: Thanks for your response, the comments helped out allot. Top dog!