# If loop to find date where values are bigger than certain threshold

Tags: matlab

I am struggling with my Matlab homework.

I have a datetime array called "date" and two arrays (X and Y) of the type double containing measurements for each time step.

I have to do the following task:

Select all time steps where both X AND Y are larger than their respective Z value. Store the dates of these time steps in a new variable. Name it 'C'

Z and Y are 52584x1 double vectors and date is a vector of the format 52584x1 datetime (dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm)

I tried:

```
%Some Dummy Data:
Y = 1:8:80
X = 2:4:40
t1 = datetime(2013,11,1,8,0,0)
t2 = datetime(2013,11,10,8,0,0)
date = t1:t2

Z = 8;

for i = length(date) 
    if X(i) > Z && Y(i) > Z
         C=date(i)
    end
end
```

I guess something is wrong with `C=date(i)`

Thankful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you need might be something like below:

```
Z = 8;
for i = 1:length(date) 
    if X(i) > Z && Y(i) > Z
         C(end+1)= date(i);
    end
end
```

**alternative**: `C = date((X>Z)& (Y>Z))` or `C = date(min([X;Y],[],1) > Z)` is a more efficient solution instead of using `for` loop

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this looks much better. However, this gives me an empty array...

Comment: @Axel.Schweiß please show some of you data, otherwise I have no idea what those variables contain

Comment: I tried to specify the data. But how can I show them? Upload the .txt file?

Comment: @Axel.Schweiß you can create some fake data for toy examples of your problem, instead of using huge and real dataset

Comment: @Axel.Schweiß with you dummy data, I don't see that `C` as an empty output....I don't know what threshold `Z` you are using when trying my code

Comment: True, but for me it does only show Nov. 10th where both conditions are given. But I am looking for all dates where X and Y is greater than 8, which should be the case for all days beginning from Nov third...

Comment: @Axel.Schweiß sorry for my typo, should be `i = 1:length(date) ` in `for-loop`

Comment: This is a really bad way of growing an array. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990695/7328782). This whole code would be better without a loop at all.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, yes, I know. A more efficient solution is to use `date((X>Z)& (Y>Z))`, while I am not sure if OP is pursuing the efficient or just want to look at the `for-loop`

Comment: @Axel.Schweiß see my updates with alternative solutions